# Symfony Voter supports method receiving ROLE and Request instead attribute and entity

Tags: symfony, symfony2-voter

The Voter seems to work on my whole app... except on this controller:

```
 $entity = $em->getReference('AppBundle:Offer',$id);
 $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('overview', $entity);
```

Where this Voter method is receiving wrong arguments ....

supports($attribute, $subject)

```
dump($attribute)-> ROLE_USER // instead 'overview'
dump($subject)-> Request Object // instead $entity
```

The Voter config is:

```
app_voter:
    class:      AppBundle\Security\Authorization\AppVoter
    public:     true
    strategy: affirmative
    arguments: ['@role_hierarchy', '@security.token_storage']
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter }
```

The problem disappears if instead 'overview' I write 'view' on the controller code.

Comment: The supports method can actually be called multiple times during the processing cycle to determine which voteOnAttribute ends up being called.  So if $subject is not an offer then supports should just return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add 'overview' to the method 'supports' :

```
  protected function supports($attribute, $subject) {
        // if the attribute isn't one we support, return false
        if (!in_array($attribute, array(self::OVERVIEW, self::VIEW, self::EDIT))) {
            return false;
        }

        // bypass if the entity is not supported
        if (!$this->isSupportedClass($subject)) {
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, same problem here. The $subject is good on voteOnAttribute but not on supports, the Subject is a Request...When I call isGrented, I give a param converter object received on parameter by Controller directly...maybe it's an advice.